# Gitlab CI/CD job order based on variable value (by group) rather than concurrently by stage

Tags: gitlab-ci, devops

I have 3 job groups. In the current setup, all jobs for a given stage are started concurrently.
I would like them run in the following order based on a $jobs variable.

```
1. prep (always first to run)
2. build1 (if build1 one is present in $jobs string variable)
3. deploy1 (ran after build1)
4. build2 (if build2 present in $jobs)
5. deploy2 (ran after build2)
6. build3 (if build3 present)
7. deploy3 (ran after build3)
```

If build1 is not present then skip build1 and start build2. If build2 is not present then start with build1, skipping build2 (missing job) and then start build3.

```
 stages:
   - prep
   - build
   - deploy

 getjobs  
  stage: prep  
  script: <script assigns string value with jobs to be ran to $jobs global variable>  
  rules:    
   -if: $CI_COMMIT_MESSAGE =~ /See  merge request  when: on_success

 build1 
  stage: build 
  needs: [getjobs] 
  script: ... 
  rules:   
   -if: $CI_COMMIT_MESSAGE =~ /See merge request  when: on_success

 deploy1 
  stage: deploy 
  needs: [build1] 
  script: ...
  rules:   
   -if: $CI_COMMIT_MESSAGE =~ /See merge request &&   when: on_success

 build2 
  stage: build 
  needs: [getjobs] 
  script: ... 
  rules:   
   -if: $CI_COMMIT_MESSAGE =~ /See merge request  when: on_success

 deploy2 
  stage: deploy 
  needs: [build2] 
  script: ... 
  rules:   
   -if: $CI_COMMIT_MESSAGE =~ /See merge request &&   when: on_success

 build3 
  stage: build 
  needs: [getjobs] 
  script: ... 
  rules:   
   -if: $CI_COMMIT_MESSAGE =~ /See merge request  when: on_success

 deploy3 
  stage: deploy 
  needs: [build3] 
  script: ... 
  rules:   
   -if: $CI_COMMIT_MESSAGE =~ /See merge request &&   when: on_success
```

I'm wondering if it's actually possible to set that kind of job order dependency keeping stages as they currently are.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `only` to control when to add jobs to pipelines

```
build1:
  script: ...
  only:
    variables:
      - $jobs =~ "build1"
```

Comment: Does this mean that the value of $jobs needs to be changed between jobs? For example, after deploy1 it needs to be set to build2 or build3?

Comment: No It must contain jobs name, for example $jobs="build1,deploy1,build3,deploy3"

Comment: Unfortunately it does not work. $jobs value is a global variable and its value cannot be changed by a script in getjobs job.